# PHP: Can't get visitor IP on shared hosting and some VPS

Tags: php, server

The problem is that I can't get visitor IP on some shared hosting or VPS.

Here is my "powerfull" function:

```
function get_IP(){
    $findIP=array(
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'REMOTE_ADDR'
    );
    $blacklistIP=array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        '255.255.255.255',
    );
    $ip = '';
    foreach($findIP as $http)
    {
        if(function_exists("getenv"))
        {
            $ip = getenv($http);
        }
        else
        {
            if (array_key_exists($http, $_SERVER) !== false){
                foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$http]) as $findIP){
                    $ip = trim($findIP);
                }
            }
        }
        if(function_exists("filter_var") && !empty($ip) && in_array($ip, $blacklistIP)===false)
        {
            if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false) return $ip;
        }
        else if(preg_match('/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/', $ip) && !empty($ip) && in_array($ip, $blacklistIP)===false)
        {
            return $ip;
        }
    }
    return '0.0.0.0';
}
```

This function work perfectly on normal servers but some shared and VPS made me a lot of problems.

Some server return me `127.0.0.1` and on some server `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`, `HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`, `HTTP_FORWARDED` and `REMOTE_ADDR` return like empty or not set.

Where is my mistake here? Is missing something or what I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Are these servers using reverse proxies to split up traffic to different hosts?

Comment: I realy don't know. I can check. That's my client's server.

Comment: @TZHX has probably hit the nail on the head. You're likely getting the IP address of a proxy server instead of the client.

Comment: That can be true but how to get client address? I need that to site can function properly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L792-L834?

I'd assume that symfony handles this properly due to its popularity. If it doesn't, could you post the result of `print_r($_SERVER)`?

Comment: This can be interesting. They use `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` to get IP but I use that in my code. What return `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, working on this I figureout the problem and I will give you answer on my problem:

```
/*
* IP Address Lookup
* @author Ivijan-Stefan Stipic
*/
function get_IP(){
    // check any protocols
    $findIP=array(
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'REMOTE_ADDR',
        'BAN_CHECK_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'
    );
    // IP blacklist - you can add array from your database
    $blacklistIP=array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        '255.255.255.255',
    );
    $ip = '';
    // start looping
    foreach($findIP as $http)
    {
        // Check in $_SERVER
        if (array_key_exists($http, $_SERVER) !== false){
            $ip=$_SERVER[$http];
        }
        // check in getenv() for any case
        if(empty($ip) && function_exists("getenv"))
        {
            $ip = getenv($http);
        }
        // Check if here is multiple IP's
        if(!empty($ip))
        {
            $ips=explode(",",$ip);
            $ipMAX=count($ips);
            if($ipMAX>0)
            {
                if($ipMAX > 1)
                    $ip=trim(end($ips));
                else
                    $ip=trim($ips[0]);
            }
        }
        // Check if IP is real and valid
        if(function_exists("filter_var") && !empty($ip) && in_array($ip, $blacklistIP)===false && filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false)
        {
            return $ip;
        }
        else if(preg_match('/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/', $ip) && !empty($ip) && in_array($ip, $blacklistIP)===false)
        {
            return $ip;
        }
    }
    return '0.0.0.0';
}
```

The problem inside of code is that sometimes X forwarders return multiple IP's comma separated what can made a problem. Also some hosts can be a IP and some banned IP addresses can visit your website. I add that rules and extract one IP what can be a pat of list. This give me a deep IP address lookup.

Thanks for help and someones -1 becouse that force me to digg deeper in the problem and solve. I think this is the most complete IP address lookup on the internet.